# Maya\python Incremental button that increment value

Tags: python, maya

I'm new in python.
I try to make a button in Maya that increments the value of the crease edges. Each time I click on it I want to make +1 to the crease value.

I tried this :

```
def crease(ignore):
    value=+1
    newvalue = value
    for i in value(int(newvalue)+1):
        maya.cmds.polyCrease(i)
```

But it doesn't work.
If somebody could help
I really appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of nesting values, when your value is under a def, it is not not stored in the global scope.

```
counter = 0

def crease(ignore):
    value = counter+1
    maya.cmds.polyCrease(v=i)
    return value

counter = crease(0)
```

if you want to keep track of the counter, you can create a global :
[Can not increment global variable from function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506973/can-not-increment-global-variable-from-function-in-python)

a dict :
[python modify a dictionary inside a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797683/python-modify-a-dictionary-inside-a-method)

or even a class.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, `cmds.polyCrease` includes a flag that does what you want:

```
cmds.polyCrease(rv=1)
```

will bump the crease value on the currently selected components by 1; a negative value will bump it down.  A global counter works from a programming standpoint but it will probably have surprising results if you hop between different objects in the scene.